# Python file scanning

Tags: python

I have a some code in a game I'm making where it stores user data on a text file called `data.txt`. The following code is when a person continues, then it will read the part where the level is stored and see where it will begin the game:

```
elif choice==("2"):
    contusername = input("Enter the name you registered with")
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        f.readline()
        for lines in f:
            name, level = lines.split()
            if name == contusername:
                userdata = level
                break

        while True:
            if level == 1:
                level1()

            elif level == 2:
                level2()
            #and so on
```

But it won't work. Python can't read the text file. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not simply test it!?

Comment: I tried. But all it does is nothing. So I am technically asking for troubleshooting

Comment: what's inside `data.txt` ?

Comment: @psal This is the format: Username Level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to cast to int:

```
userdata = int(level)
```

Other way your `userdata` are strings of form `'1\n'`

Also, you want to use this `userdata` in comparison, not `level`

```
while True:
    if userdata == 1:
        level1()
```

p.s. I don't know whether this `while True:` statement is correct, as only a code excerpt is presented, but it also looks suspitious for me.

Comment: After I entered the name, it just exits.

Comment: Are you sure that the File is actually read? Try printing the lines!

Comment: I'm getting"userdata is not defined". how come? In the text file, I setted the name(Bob)in the right format. Is python not picking up the split part?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a Type problem. Reading from a file will give you a string, but you are checking for integers.

Try forcing the level numbers to an `int`.

```
elif choice==("2"):
    contusername = input("Enter the name you registered with")
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        f.readline()
        for lines in f:
            name, level = lines.split()
            if name == contusername:
                userdata = level
                break
        level = int(level)  # <-- force the level to an integer
        while True:
            if level == 1:
                level1()

            elif level == 2:
                level2()
```

Comment: In this solution `userdata` is never used. You could just leave the line 'userdata = level' out.

Comment: true.  I just copy/pasted the OP's code and added the type casting

Comment: Can i try this:elif choice == 2:
        contusername = raw_input("Please enter your neame registered:")
        with open("data.txt") as f:
            f.readline()
            for lines in f:
                name, level = lines.split()
                if name == contusername:
                    userdata = int(level)
                    break


            while True:
                if userdata == 1:
                    level1()

                elif userdata == 2:

Comment: Please Edit your Question with the current code if the current problem is still Part of this question.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
elif choice == "2":
    contusername = raw_input("Enter the name you registered with")
    with open("data.txt") as f:
        for lines in f.readlines():
            name, level = lines.split()
            if name == contusername:
                userdata = int(level)
                break

        while True:
            if userdata == 1:
                level1()
            elif userdata == 2:
                level2()
```

Comment: I have tried it, but after I enter my name, it just does nothing. I think it has a trouble with the line splitting.